# How to add sites to search in Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am new to Google Custom Search API.
In order to use this API, I know it is necessary to create a Google Custom Search Engine in http://www.google.com/cse

However, it's really confused why I should add sites to search in creating a custom search engine? Does it mean Custom Search API are only limited to the specific websites defined?

I cannot use Custom Search API to search Internet via Google?

Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the websites you enter there are for an onsite search, but you can change the settings to a "world-wide-web" search. so its possible to use the cse for searching items on your own site and on the internet. the results of possible matches on your site are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

By default, CSEs search only specified sites.  However, once you have created the CSE, you can go to the sites tab in the control panel and remove all sites.  The CSE then should search the entire internet.  (Of course, you'll probably want to add some refinements or something to give your search some value to distinguish it from a standard google search.)